# Tool for knowing what to set auction prices to

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Economies differ and if you're new to the auction house, it can be overwhelming. Lately when I want to sell something, I have to see if anyone else is selling it also and figure out what the average price is so I can put up an item with a reasonable price. If no one has the item up, I have to resort to googling and other tactics.

Is there a tool which just tells you when you're creating auctions what it sells best at or something similar? Any kind of add-on that is easy to use and not cumbersome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Auctioneer](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/auctioneer).  This fancy add-on has a full array of fancy options to customize your desired profit, current market prices, averages, etc.  This helped me a lot over time achieve maximum profit while still producing a sale.

[image]

Comment: I saw this add-on and it looks overwhelming. Is there a trivial way to see how much an item should be put up for?

Comment: It can be rather advanced and rather easy at the same time.  Once you have it installed, do a scan on the auction house.  (takes about 12 minutes) Then you select your % profit in the sell page, and post the sale.  That's it.

Answer (score 2):

For a light-weight addon that does exactly that, check out [Auctionator](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/auctionator).

You just drag an item to it's sell tab, and it recommends the sell price for you.

[image]

Comment: +1, I know Auctioneer is more capable and powerful, but I have always loved the relative simplicity and ease-of-use of Auctionator.